# Perl - best way to trap exit status and capture log for an external command

Tags: perl, db2

need to run and external command, write output to a logfile and trap exit status

`my $cmd = "db2 \"insert into schema.tablea (id, name, city) values (99, 'Micheal', 'London')\" ";
open my $log, ">", "logfile.log";
my $rt = open(OUTPUT,"$cmd 2>&1 | " );
while (<OUTPUT>){
   chomp;
   print $log $_, "\n";
   print $_, "\n";
}
close(OUTPUT);
close($log);
print "Exit status is $rt\n";`

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at IPC::Run or IPC::Open3

Comment: Any reason in particular why you don't want to use DBI and DBD::DB2?

Answer (score 1):

`close` for this kind of handle will set `$?` as [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) does.

```
die $! if $? == -1;
die "Killed by ".( $? & 0x7F ) if $? & 0x7F;
die "Exited with ".( $? >> 8 ) if $? >> 8;
```

If you're going to shell out anyway, you might as well consider

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
system("$cmd 2>&1 | tee ".shell_quote($log));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Capture::Tiny:

```
    use Capture::Tiny ':all';
    use File::Slurp;
    use autodie;

    ($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = tee sub {
        system("echo hello; exit 15");
    };

    write_file('logfile.log', $stdout);
    print "exit: ", $exit >> 8, "\n";
```

See "perldoc -f system" for the explanation of "$exit >> 8".